# Javascript: date conversion

Tags: javascript

How can I write the Dateformat for "2010-12-07 17:53:17.0_getCreated_10032" in Javascript
so that sorting can be done accordingly?

Thanks in advance,

Joseph

Comment: @joseph or Joseph please stop asking the same question over and over again, it's only irritating people that you ignore their answers.

Comment: I've merged some of the accounts.  Joseph, please consider registering (since you seem to keep creating new accounts), and do stop asking the same question over and over.  If you need to clarify, you can edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what that stuff ont he end is - up to the getCreated bit it looks like a MySQL datetime field.

first, get rid of that:

```
var str = "2010-12-07 17:53:17.0_getCreated_10032";
str = str.replace(/(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*$/g, '$1');  // now is 2010-12-07 17:53:17
```

then you need to move the year so it reads M-D-Y...

```
str = str.replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/g, '$2-$3-$1');
```

now it's a valid date string so you can feed it to the Date constructor...

```
var date = new Date(str);
```

and to sort it, cast it as a number

```
var num = Number(date);
```

so alltogehter it looks like this:

```
var str = "2010-12-07 17:53:17.0_getCreated_10032";
str = str.replace(/(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*$/g, '$1');
str = str.replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/g, '$2-$3-$1');
var date = new Date(str);
var num = Number(date);
```